# How to restrict to the initial position of a string in this regex?

Tags: python, regex

```
(1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|17|28|29|30|31)day$
```

Given a string `'233day'`, it matches `'3day'`, which is bad. I need to add a condition: to make 1...31 be the initial position of the string. For example, `'3day'` will match, but `'233day'` won't match.

I tried to add `^`, but it doesn't work:

```
(^1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|17|28|29|30|31)day$
```

Comment: Move the marker before the parenthesis, `^(1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the ^ outside the capturing group.

```
^(1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|17|28|29|30|31)day$
```

a good tool for regex debugging is regex101.com

Answer (score 3):

Better approach than hardcoding:

```
regex = r"\A(?:3[01]|[12]\d|[1-9])day\Z"
```

Comment: What does the \A, \Z mean?

Comment: @marlon `\A` for start of the string, and `\Z` asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any). You can go on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) and play around with it.

Comment: Etoneja: But (?:[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]) doesn't match [1,2,3,31]. If you test '31', it matches '3' & '1' individually, not '31' together.

Comment: @marlon I have edited my answer - please check now.

Comment: Can I use ^ and $ to replace \A and \Z?

Comment: @marlon Yes, you can. The difference will be in the handling the carriage return at the end of the line. Try by yourself in python shell: `re.match(r"asdf$", "asdf\n")` and `re.match(r"asdf\Z", "asdf\n")` to feel it.

Answer (score 0):

The caret should be outside the group:

```
>>> import re
>>> rr = re.compile(r)
>>> rr.match('3day')
<re.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='3day'>
>>> rr.match('233day')
```

Comment: Forgot to paste the pattern

Comment: That's interesting, the pattern is there `r='^(1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|17|28|29|30|31)day$'` but is not visible in the answer inside the "```"

Comment: Did we find a bug?